# Is there a form of 'for' that evaluates the "expression list" every time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
lt = 1000 #list primes to ...
remaining = list(range(2, lt + 1)) #remaining primes

for c in remaining: #current "prime" being tested
    for t in remaining[0: remaining.index(c)]: #test divisor
        if c % t == 0 and c != t:
            if c in remaining:
                remaining.remove(c)
```

If you don't need context:

How can I either re-run the same target-list value, or use something other than for that reads the expression list every iteration?

If you need context:

I am currently creating a program that lists primes from 2 to a given value (lt). I have a list 'remaining' that starts as all integers from 2 to the given value. One at a time, it tests a value on the list 'c' and tests for divisibility one by one by all smaller numbers on the list 't'. If 'c' is divisible by 't', it removes it from the list. By the end of the program, in theory, only primes remain but I have run into the problem that because I am removing items from the list, and for only reads remaining once, for is skipping values in remaining and thus leaving composites in the list.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't directly possible, mainly because it's almost always the wrong design. You can simulate it with a bit of verbosity—just do a `while True:` or `for i in itertools.count():` with a `if i > len(remaining): break` at the start of the loop or the like, and then use `remaining[i]` in place of `c`.

Comment: Also, if you're calling `list.remove` in a loop, that's almost always a sign that you're either not keeping track of indices you should be, or not using the right algorithm. Each `remove` has to scan the list to find the very same value that you just found. (Plus, `if c in remaining` is _also_ scanning the list, which implies that you probably wanted something else, maybe a set.)

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is almost never the right answer (and it's definitely not the right answer here, for reasons I'll get to later), which is why Python doesn't give you a way to do it automatically. In fact, it's illegal for delete from or insert into a list while you're iterating over it, even if CPython and other Python implementations usually don't check for that error.

But there is a way you can simulate what you want, with a little verbosity:

```
for i in range(remaining.index(c)):
    if i >= remaining.index(c): break
    t = remaining[i]
```

Now we're not iterating over `remaining`, we're iterating over its indices. So, if we remove values, we'll be iterating over the indices of the modified list. (Of course we're not really relying on the `range` there, since the `if…break` tests the same thing; if you prefer `for i in itertools.count():`, that will work too.)

And, depending on what you want to do, you can expand it in different ways, such as:

```
end = remaining.index(c)
for i in range(end):
    if i >= end: break
    t = remaining[i]
    # possibly subtract from end within the loop
    # so we don't have to recalculate remaining.index(c)
```

… and so on.

---

However, as I mentioned at the top, this is really not what you want to be doing. If you look at your code, it's not only looping over all the primes less than `c`, it's calling a bunch of functions inside that loop that *also* loop over either all the primes less than `c` or your entire list (that's how `index`, `remove`, and `in` work for lists), meaning you're turning linear work into quadratic work.

The simplest way around this is to stop trying to mutate the original list to remove composite numbers, and instead build a set of primes as you go along. You can search, add, and remove from a set in constant time. And you can just iterate your list in the obvious way because you're no longer mutating it.

---

Finally, this isn't actually implementing a proper prime sieve, but a much less efficient algorithm that for some reason everyone has been teaching as a Scheme example for decades and more recently translating into other languages. See [The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) for details, or [this project](https://github.com/abarnert/primetable) for sample code in Python and Ruby that shows how to implement a proper sieve and a bit of commentary on performance tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

(In the following, I ignore the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) of finding primes *using* a "mutable `for`".)

It's not entirely trivial to design an iteration over a sequence with well-defined (and efficient) behavior when the sequence is modified.  In your case, where the sequence is merely being depleted, one reasonable thing to do is to use a list but "delete" elements by replacing them with a special value.  (This makes it easy to preserve the current iteration position and avoids the cost of shifting the subsequent elements.)

To make it efficient to skip the deleted elements (both for the outer iteration and any inner iterations like in your example), the special value should be (or contain) a count of any following deleted elements.  Note that there is a special case of deleting the current element, where for maximum efficiency you must move the cursor while you still know how far to move.